# How to use vector images in Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, swift, pdf, vector

I've drawn up an image in Adobe Illustrator CS6. I export/save the image as a PDF. In Xcode, I create an image set and set the scale factor to `Single Vector`.

Yet when I use the image in my app, it still appears pixilated.

I've used vector images in older versions of Xcode (6.1 & 6.2) and it worked fine. Why is it not working in 6.4?

Comment: It should work. Xcode makes the conversion to bitmaps at compile-time and I'm thinking perhaps there is a build issue. Have you tried the Clean Build Folder command? (command+option+shift+K)

Comment: Are you testing on a actual device, or the simulator?

Comment: tested on both but still didn't work

Comment: Can you shed some light on how you are using the image? Are you 100% confident it isn't due to how you use it?

Comment: Is the app icon pixilated?

Comment: I'm just using UIImageView within a view controller. And I don't have an app icon yet, though I will put a placeholder to see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [article](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/). It describes how to save vector image correctly and how to use it in Xcode.

**IMPORTANT TO KNOW:** Xcode slices your `vector` image to needed dimension. E.g. if you'll put 50x50 vector image it will create 50x50(x1), 100x100(x2), 150x150(x3) images. So you should to save `original vector` image for x1 dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on the simulator, try testing on an actual device. If you look at the images on all the other apps that are in the simulator, you will notice that they are all pixilated also.